# $A(x)=(1+\frac{r}{100})^x(\$k)$, $B(x)=(1+\frac{sx}{100})(\$k)$. $A(10)$=$B(10)$. Which is greater $A(11)$ or $B(11)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Alice invests some money at an annually compounded interest rate of $r$%. Bob invests the same amount at a simple interest rate of $s$%. If their investsments are worth the same after $10$ years, then which of their investments is worth more after $11$ years?

Let $A(x)$ be the amount of money Alice has after $x$ years and $B(x)$ be the amount of money Bob has after $x$ years.

$$A(10)=B(10)$$
$$(1+\frac{r}{100})^{10}=(1+\frac{s}{10})$$.

If we consider the graphs of $y=A(x)$ and $y=B(x)$, I think these graphs will only intersect when $x=0$ or $x=10$ but that's not helping so slove this problem. I'm stuck!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, after some convoluted algebraic manipulations, it looks like the issue resolves to $$\frac{11}{11 - k} ~~\text{versus}~~ \left(1.1\right)^k.$$

Comment: You have two convex increasing functions starting at the same value, and one eventually exceeding the other.  Can they intersect in more than two points? what would the graph look like?

Comment: @Macavity  $B(x)$ is linear and it's graph will be a straight line going up and toward the right. $A(x)$ will intersect the graph of $B(x)$ when $x=10$. The  graph of $A(x)$ should look like half a U.

Comment: The exponential function will raise faster than the linear fuction so $A(x)>B(x)$ after $10$ years?

Comment: @Macavity $B$ is  eventually bigger?!  Please see my previous comment.